# HtmlUnit wait for ajax response

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have this project where I need to use one site to get data from it.
So the thing is: using htmlunit I fill textbox with my data, then I press on anchor which is using ajax do download content I need and dynamically change HTML page, showing content in modal window. But after i use .click() on anchor I get the same page, without been updated, and after looking around for solution I found this on web:

> HtmlUnit will execute the Ajax call and will update the page. Just
>   observe that, unlike a regular page loading, the click() call will not
>   wait for the completion of the Ajax request. It will proceed to the
>   next line of code right away.

Here is my code:

```
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("myUrl");
System.out.println(page.asXml());
final HtmlForm form =    page.getFirstByXPath("//form[@action='myFormAction']");
final HtmlTextInput input = form.getInputByName("url");
input.setText(vacancyURL);

List<HtmlAnchor> anchors = page.getAnchors();
HtmlAnchor link = null;

    for (HtmlAnchor anchor : anchors) {
        String str = anchor.asText();
        if (anchor.asText().equals("Start"))
            link = anchor;
    }

    HtmlPage page2 = link.click(); //I think this is a problem
```

Any ideas how can I click on anchor and wait for ajax to receive response back, and fill page with data(on browser everything works great)? I really need help, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you have to wait for execution, best is to retrying for some time until page is not updated (using any condition)
here is example of code

```
    int input_length = page.getByXPath("//input").size();
    int tries = 5; 
    while (tries > 0 && input_length < 12) { //you can change number of tries and condition according to your need
        tries--;
        synchronized (page) {
            page.wait(2000); //wait
        }
        input_length = page.getByXPath("//input").size(); //input length is example of condtion
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

oh, this is an old question..i want to share my solution..
i think `page.wait` is disgusting...because u won't get notified immediately when ajax request finished,there will be a delay..
my answer is using method

`com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManager#waitForJobs`

invoke example: `page.getEnclosingWindow().getJobManager().waitForJobs(1000);`

page is a type of `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage`

1000 is timeoutMillis which means the max time in millis u want to wait

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tasawer, relying upon a state / element is usually a good thing.

Depending the javascript on the remote website, you can also ask the webclient how many javscripts threads are still in progress. For eg:

```
int wait = 0;
int nbProcess = 1;
while (nbProcess > 0 && wait < 10) {
   nbProcess = client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
      if (wait == 9) {
         System.err.println("** needs more time ** ");
      }
   wait++;
}
```

Warning : some sites can have one or more scripts perpetually running so the minimal nbProcess could be 1, 2 ...

Link to [javadoc](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#waitForBackgroundJavaScript(long))